# How to deal with large constantly updating images

Tags: java, swing, out-of-memory, bufferedimage

I'm working on a painting application that users can create any size of image they want. I'm using a BufferedImage to draw on, and then drawing that image onto a JPanel. However, when I try to make an image that is, for instance, 12000 x 12000, I get an Out Of Memory Error. I figure that I'm approaching this problem wrong, as other applications such as Photoshop and Paint.net have managed to do it. Any tips on what the logic should be for using large images in Java?

**Edit:**
this is the maximum size I'll allow in my program. If I run this, however, I still get an error due to lack of memory. So I'm guessing it's not possible to store all of it in one image?

```
public class BigImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400 * 256, 400 * 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

}
```

Comment: May having a look at [this](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) might provide you with a better idea of what an `OutOfMemoryError` actually is

Comment: Obviously it's a memory management problem. The issue you are facing is that you are keeping all the datas in memory. As a naive approach, what you could do, is to only load in memory the zone you are editing !

Comment: LouisF. I tried doing that, but I couldn't get the scrolling to be smooth, so I took it out. I'll research smooth scrolling with that method. MadProgrammer, I read the article, and I think I understand how Java's garbage collection works, but if I make a new project with the only object created being a BufferedImage, it still throws an error. I'll edit my code to give an example

Comment: `new BufferedImage(400 * 256, 400 * 256 ..` Uh-huh.. so you want to support a 10 **Giga** pixel image?  Good luck with that.  As an aside, a friend was making a 6000 x 6000 pixel image (36 megapixel) for me using Photoshop, and the machine (admittedly a laptop) was just about dying. I find it hard to believe that Photoshop on an average desktop computer could handle an image gigapixels in size.

Answer (score 0):

A BufferedImage is basically a 1D array, and in Java you cannot allocate something bigger than an int, so the maximum you can have is:

```
int[] array = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE] ;
```

IF you do need something bigger, you have to do it yourself using the class Unsafe. [See an example in this library](https://gitlab.com/ICM-VisLab/JLargeArrays).